# How to get all the data starting current week of monday to saturday only using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, where-clause

I have question regarding on mysql, How to get all the data of the current week starting Monday to Saturday. let's say the date today is October 5, 2020 (Monday) the only data I want to get is from starting October 5, 2020 until October 10, 2020

**Goal: To get the data starting monday to saturday only of the current week.**

I have here my sample script that I already created.

```
$flavors_breakdown_summary_report = DB::select('
SELECT item
     , item_category
     , unit
     , SUM(item_qty) as flavors_item_qty
     , op.receipt_code
     , created_at
     , is_payment_submit 
  FROM order_process as op
  LEFT 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT receipt_code
 , status
 , is_payment_submit 
  FROM order_process_reference) opr 
    ON op.receipt_code = opr.receipt_code
    WHERE op.item_category = ? 
   AND yearweek(DATE(op.created_at), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1) 
   AND is_payment_submit = ? 
   AND opr.status = ?  
 GROUP 
    BY item 
 ORDER 
    BY item ASC
',['Flavored','1','Stock']);
```

Output:

[image: Output]

As you can see the order date created is september 28, 2020 - The date today in our country is October 4, 2020. which mean this script is wrong.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

> get the data starting monday to saturday only of the current week.

Consider:

```
where op.created_at >= current_date - interval weekday(current_date) day
  and op.created_at < current_date - interval (weekday(current_date) - 6)  day
```

Comment: let me try on this, but will give you like. if you have a sample fiddle much better to see if this work well. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is correct.
`'2020-09-28'` is a Monday and it is the 1st day of the current week and `'2020-10-04'` is a Sunday and the last day of the current week.
So both dates belong to the same week.

But you don't want results for Sundays, so add another condition to exclude Sundays by using the function [`DAYOFWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

```
AND yearweek(DATE(op.created_at), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1)
AND DAYOFWEEK(DATE(op.created_at)) <> 1 -- not a Sunday
```

Comment: Hi forpas, do you have sample fiddle or sample created date. to prove? very well thankful  if so.

Comment: @DevGe To prove what? Today is a Sunday. So when you run your code **today** you get the results of all the previous week which started on Monday 2020-09-28. There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Hi forpas, Your script is not correct. Based on your script I am still get the previous data which is wrong. as you read on my thead. I want to fetch or select only the monday to saturday on the current week.

Comment: Previous data of what? If you run the query on a Monday you get the results of that day only. If you run the query on a Saturday you get the results of previous Monday until that Saturday. If you run the query on a Sunday you get the results of the previous week: of previous Monday until that Saturday. What is wrong with that?

Comment: straight to the point, I want to get only the data from monday to saturday of the current week. so which means starting october 5, 2020 to october 10, 2020.

Comment: based on your script i am still getting the september 28, 2020. which means not correct. because that data is on the previous week

Comment: `yearweek('2020-09-28', 1)` returns `202040` but `yearweek(curdate(), 1)` returns `202041`. So you are doing something wrong because `yearweek(DATE(op.created_at), 1) = yearweek(curdate(), 1)` would fail. Check this:https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=113f02d2583b39304fd6b53ac9cf9c9b